# How to implement Python's digest function in Raku?

Tags: hash, raku

In Python, there is a function called `digest` from `hashlib` module, which returns the digest of a byte string:

```py
import hashlib

id = "65766"
song_id = bytearray(id, "u8")

m = hashlib.md5(song_id)
result = m.digest()
print(result)

# Output
# b"\xc9j\xa4/vy}+'\xe6\x8e\xe4\xcc\xd8\xa8\xc8"
```

I find a module from raku.land named Digest::MD5, but it doesn't provide the digest sub:

```perl
my $d = Digest::MD5.new;
my $id = "65766";
my Buf $md5-buf = $d.md5_buf($id);

# ???
```

And I don't want to introduce `Inline::Python` or `Inline::Perl5` into my project, Is it possible to implement digest sub in Raku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Try the `md5` sub of the `Digest` package.

## `Digest`

A glance at [raku.land](https://raku.land/?q=Digest) shows various options. The first one was last updated an hour ago, and while that doesn't prove anything about quality or functionality, it's at least "promising". (And it's grondilu. I trust cosimo too, but the updates suggest grondilu is engaged and cosimo isn't.)

So I suggest you read `Digest`'s README and/or install it and read its code. At a glance I would expect the `md5` sub to work.

## `Digest::MD5`

From its README:

> An interface-compatible port of Perl 5 Digest::MD5

Raku's standard strings are dramatically different from Perl's or Python's. I won't comment further other than to say this seems likely to be a major source of friction that is pointless unless you really need to have interface compatibility with Perl.

> Should work with latest (**2012**.01) release of Rakudo

Wow. It's had an update in 2017, but I see unresolved PRs and, well, to be as open minded as possible, I'll say this package *might* work for folk who are:

- *Needing the same interface as the corresponding Perl package*.
- OK with presuming that *everything is as it was more than 10 years ago* (4 years before the first official version of the language and compiler were released) or updating the package if needed.
- Willing to consider a package that *seems to be no longer actively stewarded*.

To be pragmatic / closed minded, I'd initially presume this package should only be considered if all of the above applies and you've failed to meet your (relatively simple/basic) needs some much more promising way.